# Drag and drop from kinetic.stage to another

Tags: drag-and-drop, kineticjs

Is it possible to do the drag and drop from stage1 to stage2 ? stage1 would be containing the draggable shapes, and stage2 would be the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, with something like this:

```
image.on('dragmove', function() {
    if ((!stage.getPointerPosition()) && image.getParent() !== layer2) {

      image.stopDrag();

      image.moveTo(layer2);
      image.position(stage2.getPointerPosition());
      image.startDrag();
      layer.draw();
      layer2.draw();      
    }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xizum/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you!! Can I make the draggable image to be 'on top' of the layers when dragged? Why does it move from behind the layers' borders?

Comment: You can't in this way. border - is not part of canvas (layer). You can just remove this border from css.